# How to filter/subset data with dcc.DropDown when there is only the id from the df available through another callback?

Tags: plotly-dash

`I am trying to first subset the data based on the user inputting dates, then I want to create a dropdown to allow the user to select a specific value in the column of the table. The challenge is that the subsetting for the inputting dates is done through a function called assessorials.assessorial_benchmark and therefore the DataTable is referencing the table id and not the actual df. Don't know how to create filters based on the id.

```
layout_page_2 = dbc.Container(
                            # Heading title for page
                            [html.H1("Unilever Assessorial Analysis",
                                style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': 'rgb(0, 128, 255)','backgroundColor':'rgb(32,32,32)', 'fontSize': 50}), 
                                dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown',
                                             options=[{'label': i , 'value': i} for i in list(kma_pairs.kma_pair)] + [{'label': 'ALL', 'value': 'ALL'}]
                                             ,value='ALL'),
                                 html.Div(id='dropdown_container'),
                                 html.Div([  
                                        # Input dates that are defined by the user that are used to subset the data
                                           "Un Start Date: ",
                                        dcc.Input(id="un_start_date",type="text",placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                           "Un End Date: ",
                                        dcc.Input(id="un_end_date",type="text",placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                        html.Br(),
                                             "Benchmark Start Date: ", 
                                        dcc.Input(id="benchmark_start_date",type="text",placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                          "Benchmark End Date: ",
                                        dcc.Input(id="benchmark_end_date",type="text",placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD")])
                                            ,
                                 # Creating the data table
                                 html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                                        #id is defined below in the callback, my_table is the same as the table: avg_perc_mode.to_dict('records') returned by the function
                                        id="kma_table",

                                        style_cell_conditional=[
                                            {
                                                'textAlign': 'center'
                                            }
                                            ],
                                        style_data={
                                            'color':'white',
                                            'backgroundColor':'rgb(32,32,32)'
                                        },
                                        style_cell={'padding': '5px'},
                                        style_header={
                                            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(32,32,32)',
                                            'color':'white',
                                            'fontWeight': 'bold'
                                        },style_data_conditional=(
                                            [{
                                                'if': {
                                                    'filter_query':'{avg_percentile} >=80',
                                                    'column_id':'avg_percentile',
                                                },
                                                'color':'red'
                                            },
                                            {'if': {
                                                    'filter_query':'{avg_percentile} < 80 && {avg_percentile} >=60',
                                                    'column_id':'avg_percentile',
                                                },
                                                'color':'rgb(255,128,0)'},
                                            {'if': {
                                                    'filter_query':'{avg_percentile} < 60 && {avg_percentile} >=40',
                                                    'column_id':'avg_percentile',
                                                },
                                                'color':'rgb(255,255,0)'},
                                            {'if': {
                                                    'filter_query':'{avg_percentile} < 40 && {avg_percentile} >=20',
                                                    'column_id':'avg_percentile',
                                                },
                                                'color':'rgb(128,255,0)'},
                                                {'if': {
                                                    'filter_query':'{avg_percentile} < 20 && {avg_percentile} >=0',
                                                    'column_id':'avg_percentile',
                                                },
                                                'color':'rgb(0,255,0)'}
                                            
                                            ]
                                        ), style_as_list_view=True),
                                html.Br(),
                                dcc.Link('Navigate to "/"', href='/'),
                                html.Br(),
                                dcc.Link('Navigate to "/page-1"', href='/page-1')
                                ]),
                                 ],fluid=True)


# index layout
app.layout = url_bar_and_content_div

# "complete" layout
app.validation_layout = html.Div([
    url_bar_and_content_div,
    layout_index,
  
])

# Index callbacks
@callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/page-1":
        return layout_page_1
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return layout_page_2
    else:
        return layout_index

# callbacks used within page 2
@callback(
    Output("kma_table","data"),
    Input("benchmark_start_date","value"),
    Input("benchmark_end_date","value"),
    Input("un_start_date","value" ),
    Input("un_end_date","value" ),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)



def update_kma_table(benchmark_start_date,benchmark_end_date,un_start_date,un_end_date,kma_pair):
    if not benchmark_start_date and not benchmark_end_date and not un_start_date and not un_end_date  :
        results = assessorials.assessorial_benchmark(start_time="2022-01-01", end_time=date.today()).copy()
        results["ship_date"] = pd.to_datetime(results["ship_date"])
        perc_mode = results.loc[results["ship_date"].between(pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01"),pd.to_datetime(date.today()))].groupby(["kma_pair","assessorial","eq_mode"],as_index=False).agg(avg_charge_amount =("charge_amount","mean"),avg_percentile =("percentile","mean"),un_count=("benchmark_count",'count'),benchmark_count =("benchmark_count","mean")).round(0).sort_values(["un_count","avg_percentile"],ascending=False).copy()
        perc_mode_subset = perc_mode[perc_mode["kma_pair"]==kma_pair].copy()
    else:
        results = assessorials.assessorial_benchmark(start_time=benchmark_start_date, end_time=benchmark_end_date).copy()
        results["ship_date"] = pd.to_datetime(results["ship_date"])
        perc_mode = results.loc[results["ship_date"].between(pd.to_datetime(un_start_date),pd.to_datetime(un_end_date))].groupby(["kma_pair","assessorial","eq_mode"],as_index=False).agg(avg_charge_amount =("charge_amount","mean"),avg_percentile =("percentile","mean"),un_count=("benchmark_count",'count'),benchmark_count =("benchmark_count","mean")).round(0).sort_values(["un_count","avg_percentile"],ascending=False).copy()
        perc_mode_subset = perc_mode[perc_mode["kma_pair"]==kma_pair].copy()
    return  perc_mode.to_dict('records')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```